# Differentiability implies continuity in $R^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let F be a function from $R^2$ to $R^2$. F is differentiable at a point (a,b) in $R^2$, prove that F is continuous at this point.

Can i write F(x,y)= F(a,b)+ c(x-a)+ d(x-b)+e
 where c,d,e are real numbers and then take limits as (x,y) tends to zero to get: limit of F(x,y) as (x,y) tends to zero is the same as F(a,b) and then conclude that F is continuous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, $f$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$ if and only if there exists a linear map $J:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ (the Jacobian) such that
$$
\lim_{||h||\to 0} \frac{||f(a+h_x,b+h_y)-f(a,b) - J(h_x,h_y)||}{||h||}=0,
$$
where $h=(h_x,h_y)$. But then, we have that
$$
\lim_{||h||\to 0} ||f(a+h_x,b+h_y)-f(a,b) - J(h_x,h_y)||=0,
$$
which implies (since $||·||$ is a norm)
$$
\lim_{||h||\to 0} f(a+h_x,b+h_y)-f(a,b) - J(h_x,h_y)=0.
$$
Finally, since $J$ is linear, we have that $\lim_{||h||\to 0} J(h_x,h_y)=(0,0)$, so we conclude that
$$
\lim_{||h||\to 0} f(a+h_x,b+h_y)-f(a,b) =0,
$$
so that $f$ is continuous.