# Complex function not continuous at $z_0$

Tags: complex-analysis

If I have a function $f(z)$ defined on a domain $D$ in the complex plane that is not continuous at a point $z_0 \in D$, can $f$ be analytic in the region $D$? or I guess another way to phrase this would be can $f$ have a derivative at $z_0$?

Comment: No, because having a derivative there implies continuity there!

Comment: Ok thank you! I was not sure if this carried from real analysis

Comment: @Abrb Identify $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1187000/differentiability-implies-continuity-in-r2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\ f\ is\ analytic \ on \ region \ D \Rightarrow\ f \ is \ continuous  \ on \ D $. Therefore $\ f $ cannot be analytic on D if there's a point in D in which $\ f$ is not continuous.

Answer (score -1):

Generally speaking, you can always rewrite f(z) as: u(x,y) + i*'v(x,y), and see (at any point z = x + i*y you like) if:
du/dx +i*dv/dx = du/dy - i*dv/dy.
If yes then it is analytic at that point.

Comment: if you take $f(z)=log(z)$ how would you prove that it doesn't satisfy CREs on the negative real axis?

Comment: Simple: 
log(Z) = log(abs(Z)) + j*atan2(im(Z) / real(Z))
you now substitude u with the first term and v with the second term, and apply my formula from above.